# regex to get everything before first number

Tags: r, regex

I can't figure out how to get this regex to work.

My sample data vector looks like this:

```
claims40 1.1010101
clinical41 391.1
...
```

It follows the pattern of:

- a name,
- followed with no spaces by a version number, and
- then various other numbers.

I'm trying to create a new column in the data frame with just the name, which can be a variable amount of characters.

So the new column should look like:

```
claims
clinical
...
```

When I try to use the expression:

```
^(.*?)\\d
```

in regexp, I don't get the correct character match length.

**Question:** What is the correct regex to capture everything in a string prior to the first number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", c("claims40 1.1010101", "clinical41 391.1"))
# [1] "claims"   "clinical"
```

Also this posix style:

```
gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", c("claims40 1.1010101", "clinical41 391.1"))
# [1] "claims"   "clinical"
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked fine. What was the issue with my code? When I tried running the regex in a tool like regex101 it returned the right value.

Comment: I don't know what is regex101. If you want to learn more on R's capabalities of regular expression, please read the help document using `?"regular expression"`

Comment: @user6079762 did you explicitly match the first group with your expression?

Comment: On the basis of the pattern, english alphabets is followed by only numbers and other characters, so we just extract the english characters only.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to match until the first digit, you could also do this

```
gsub("^(.+?)(?=\\d).*", "\\1", c("claims40 1.1010101", "clinical41 391.1"), perl = TRUE)

[1] "claims"   "clinical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also with `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_extract(c("claims40 1.1010101", "clinical41 391.1"), "^[[:alpha:]]+")
# [1] "claims"   "clinical"
```

This "extracts" the alphabetical characters instead of removing everything else.